Is screen share over DLNA possible?
I am trying to livestream my pc screen to a pair or DJI goggles 2 for FPV flying in the simulator. Their interface is extremely basic and does not allow for any configuration or plugins to be downloaded. They have an open interface as a DLNA renderer. I have got files to upload to a local server then stream to the headphones. But I would like to be able to livestream the screen of my pc to then screen of the goggles. Any advice of software that will make this possible. I was trying to use VLC media player but I don’t understand the settings well enough to know why it’s not working.
I am using a media server to then read the file and send it to the goggles but am open to trying other softwares
